# Tika Audio Duration

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am working on finding the audio duration of mp3 files using tika. I have collected the following metadata after extraction. The audio duration seems to be different from the original duration(2 mins 12 seconds = 132 seconds).

Audio file: https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3

Metadata: [image: Metadata]

The xmpDM:Duration is around 132236.921875 (in seconds I assume) which seems to be way longer than original audio. I have tested the same with video file and the correct duration(in seconds) is present in the key.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a fixed set of units... http://tika.apache.org/1.24.1/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/XMPDM.html#DURATION doesn't list one. For MP3 the duration is measured in milliseconds, see http://tika.apache.org/1.24.1/api/org/apache/tika/parser/mp3/AudioFrame.html#getDuration--

Comment: I've raised this on the Apache Tika dev list, see/follow [this thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r3b9fd864a9ab897bf0f2a53c2d6fd5f770b9688f8425ab0877e20b6b%40%3Cdev.tika.apache.org%3E)

Comment: @Gagravarr has the issue fixed in tika 1.x and 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

Good news, this longstanding bug has finally been fixed! And should be in a release fairly soon (likely April 2021)

Coming in Apache Tika 1.26 and Apache Tika 2.0, MP3s will now match all the other audiovisual file formats, and the duration will be in Seconds.

Additionally, the javadocs for `xmpDM:duration` now also make clear they're in Seconds, to avoid the initial confusion.

See
https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/a4c92579d2a012e0296f057b70dd9fb2d0842445/CHANGES.txt#L11 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3318 for a bit more info.